# Lightbox2 creates another layout on load

Tags: symfony, lightbox2

I'm trying add Lightbox plugin to my proyect, I need to use it on users images, but when I load the page Ligthbox another div without images which have position absolute and superimpose on all page. So, plugin 
behavior continues being normally. You can see the problem on this image:
[Lightbox2 Bad Behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6x2K.png)

The funniest thing that I have other page with Lightbox implemented, but there is no problems. I use the exactly same code on both parts of proyect, so here you have:

```
{% if image != null and image != '' %}
    <a id="avatar" href="{{ asset(item.getWebPath) }}" data-lightbox="image" data-title="{{ 'field.avatar'|trans }}">{{ image }}</a>
{% endif %}
{% set image2 = entity_field(item, 'path2', definition_fields['path2']) %}
   {% if image2 != '' and image2 != null %}
       <a id="handwriting" href="{{ asset(item.getWebPath2) }}" data-lightbox="image" data-title="{{ 'field.image_writting'|trans }}">{{ image2 }}</a>
   {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

This block have Twig code, but the main it's just on the links. Do you find any problem or have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have **http://** at the beginning of your url inside the Twig string? Need the full path to load correctly. Greetings.

Comment: It is not needed add protocol to an import script file. But here you have my code: <script src="{{ asset('js/lightbox.min.js') }}"></script>